# Dynamically reference class properties

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sumobj = { 'foo':"apple",'bar':"banana" };
var prop1 = 'foo';

document.write( sumobj.prop1 + "<br />" );
</script>
```

I'd like to be able to do something similar to the above but this displays 'undefined' presently.

Is there anyway to do this, or something close to it?

Comment: On the off-chance I tried using [] syntax while screwing around. Makes sense...in a javascript way.  In case anyone has a similar question use obj_instance[variable]

Comment: In javascript, objects and associative arrays are the same thing, I believe.

Comment: @pimvdb good catch.  thanks for linking over there.

Comment: @MattH. you should accept [wutz's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016594/dynamically-reference-class-properties/8016616#8016616) answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
sumobj[prop1]
```